# matlab - object segmentaion

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

How to use masks operations and morphological filters to segment the object as shown in image c:
where a is the given image, b is the background(no idea why is this given), c is what we aim for:

[image]

I thought binarizing the image would help, but the result is like so:

[image]

otherwise, I Intuitively don't see how is that possible

I thought of "Segmentation Using Morphological Watersheds" but I am not sure if this is the right way to go

Comment: I have been struggling with this question for 2 hours. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually having the background makes this much easier:

```
A = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('a.png'))); % image
B = im2double(rgb2gray(imread('b.png'))); % background

D = abs(A-B)>0.12; % difference > threshold
D = imerode(D, strel('rectangle', [2 2])); % reducing spots
C = A;
C(D)=1; 
subplot 121, imshow(D)
subplot 122, imshow(C)
```

[image]